# Как написать запрос для трёх связанных таблиц (many-to-many)?

Tags: sql, postgresql

У меня есть две таблицы, между которыми связь many - to - many (main_table, table_2). Между ними есть промежуточная таблица (table_1). Как достать данные из таблицы main_table, в которых есть необходимое значение в table_2?

Привожу структуру таблиц:

```
main_table:
 -id: not null,
-column1,
-column2,
-column3
-------------

table_1:
-id: not null,
-main_table_id: not null,
-column1,
-column2,
-column3
-------------

table_2:
-id: not null,
-table_1_id: not null,
-necessary_column: not null, string
-------------
```

Соответственно, необходимо достать данные из main_table, в которых есть некоторое установленное значение из table_2 (можно, например, взять value)

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035), пункты 5 и 3.

Answer (score 0):

А в чем именно проблема?

В данном случае хватит обычного запроса из нескольких таблиц. Главное условия "связи" таблиц не забыть и правильно их указать.

Как-то так может быть

```sql
SELECT main_table.column1 
FROM main_table, table_1, table_2
WHERE main_table.id = table_1.main_table_id AND table_1.id = table_2.table_1_id
AND table_2.necessary_column = 'value'
```

Т.е. делаем выборку поля **column1** из таблицы **main_table**. В FROM указываем все таблицы, которые участвуют в запросе.
Дальше в WHERE не забываем указать условия по которым таблицы связаны друг с другом.
И так же указываем условие для поля из **table_2**, по котором нужно сделать выборку.

Comment: Не надо использовать comma-style joins, пишите явно JOIN с условиями связывания.

Comment: еще и `distinct` понадобится

Comment: @Akina а чем такой вариант плох? Ну кроме религиозных причин.

Comment: Явный JOIN визуально разделяет условия связывания и условия отбора, делая текст запроса более понятным. Плюс единообразен для внутренних и внешних соединений.

Comment: @Akina, спасибо. В общем-то мнение имеет право на жизнь. Но все курсы и учебники по SQL, которые мне встречались, они сначала рассказывают про выборку из нескольких таблиц, а потом уже про JOINы. Тут как я понял автор вопроса из совсем начинающих. И я посчитал, что такой вариант будет проще для понимания.

Comment: Разница между явным JOIN on <условие> и WHERE <условие> может оказаться очень большим, особенно для больших таблиц. Все таки декартово произведение двух таблиц - очень избыточная операция.